# PHP loop through folder and echo images in html error

Tags: php, foreach

I just can't get this to work what is wrong here?

```
 $files = scandir('gallery/');
 if ($files !== false) 
 {
    foreach($files as $f) {
      if ($f == '..' || $f == '.')
          continue;     
      echo '<li><img src="gallery/'.$f.'" alt="'.$f.'" title=""></li>'."\n";
    }
 }
```

the folder is in my root folder named "gallery". The images are inside..

I always get this error:

> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in "MYDOCUMENT.PHP" on line 101.

Comment: What’s the output of `var_dump($files);`?

Comment: can you be more specific, what do i have do to? I'm new to php...

Comment: On the line just below `$files = scandir('gallery/');` put `var_dump($files); die();` and run the code. Give us the output.

Comment: You might want to consider using `glob()` .
`$files = glob('gallery/*.{jpeg,gif,png}', GLOB_BRACE);`

Comment: Check `is_array($files)` and the try `foreach`

Comment: Now i'm getting: array(13) { [0]=> string(1) "." [1]=> string(2) ".." [2]=> string(27) "B-0062_00203_Screenshot.png" [3]=> string(27) "B-0062_00204_Screenshot.png" [4]=> string(27) "B-0062_00205_Screenshot.png" [5]=> string(27) "B-0062_00211_Screenshot.png" [6]=> string(27) "B-0062_00291_Screenshot.png" [7]=> string(27) "B-0062_00292_Screenshot.png" [8]=> string(27) "B-0062_00328_Screenshot.png" [9]=> string(27) "B-0062_00344_Screenshot.png" [10]=> string(27) "B-0062_00345_Screenshot.png" [11]=> string(27) "B-0062_00347_Screenshot.png" [12]=> string(27) "B-0062_00348_Screenshot.png" }

Comment: Well if anyone is still struggling to loop through directory, You can follow this answer on SO, 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/22480037/4806585

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php
$files = scandir('gallery/');
if ($files !== false) 
{
    foreach(is_array($files) as $f) {
    if ($f == '..' || $f == '.')
?>
    <li><img src="<?php echo 'gallery/'.$f ?>" alt="<?php echo $f ?>" title="">
<?php
   }
} 
?>
```

Comment: How does it work? The function [is_array](http://php.net/is_array) will return `true` if `$files` is an array, `false` otherwise. And how do you iterate over a boolean value with a [foreach](http://php.net/foreach) loop?

Answer (score 2):

This works, for me...:

```
<?php
    $files = scandir('gallery/');
    if ($files !== false) {
        foreach($files as $f) {
            if ($f == '..' || $f == '.') continue;
            echo $f . "<br>\n";
        }
    }
?>
```

It's quite the same code as yours... So check the "gallery/" directory contents...

Comment: ok this echos the names of the images. how can i echo the images itself?

Comment: O.k... Your code prints html which correctly references <src> image tags... So you should check the images are readable by the web server user...

Comment: hm they should be readable, why shouldn't they?Like i said the code prints the names of the images but doesn't display the images

Comment: The logic is: PHP code prints HTML with the *name* of the images. The browser (IE, Firefox, Chrome, ...) which interpets the HTML retrieves the images from the server and displays them...

Comment: i was missing a '/' before the variable.. my bad. it works now thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

change foreach to:

```
 foreach((array)$files as $f)
```

the code may be:

```
 $files = scandir('gallery/');
 if ($files !== false) 
 {
    foreach((array)$files as $f) {
      if ($f == '..' || $f == '.')
          continue;     
      echo '<li><img src="gallery/'.$f.'" alt="'.$f.'" title=""></li>'."\n";
    }
 }
```

Comment: didn't change anything

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't validate the array with :

```
if ($files !== false)
```

But by doing :

```
if (is_array($files) && count($files) > 0) {
```

Or else you'll get warnings like this one.

[EDIT]
And consider using glob like one guy said.
This will work with that function.

Example:

```
if (is_array($files) && count($files) > 0) {
   foreach(glob('gallery/*.{jpeg,gif,png}', GLOB_BRACE)) {
      // code here
   }
}
```