# loop through the files in a folder in php

Tags: php

i have searched through the Internet and found the scrip to do this but am having some problems to read the file names.

**here is the code**

```
$dir = "folder/*";
 foreach(glob($dir) as $file)  
 {  
 echo $file.'</br>';  
}
```

this display  in this format

```
folder/s0101.htm
folder/s0692.htm
```

for some reasons i want to get them in this form.

```
s0101.htm
s0692.htm
```

can anyone tell me how to do this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Just use [`basename()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.basename.php) wrapped around the `$file` variable.

```
<?php
$dir = "folder/*";
foreach(glob($dir) as $file)
{
    if(!is_dir($file)) { echo basename($file)."\n";}
}
```

The above code ignores the directories and only gets you the filenames.

Answer (score 5):

You can use [**`pathinfo`**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php) function to get file name from dir path

```
$dir = "folder/*";
 foreach(glob($dir) as $file) {  
  $pathinfo = pathinfo($file);
  echo $pathinfo['filename']; // as well as other data in array print_r($pathinfo);
}
```