# How to get image width and height on a group of image in PHP

Tags: php, html, image, getimagesize

I have to get the width and height of hundreds of images.

I got this php to work on one image:

```
<?php list($width, $height) = getimagesize($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] ."/path/file.jpg"); ?>
<img src="/path/file.jpg" alt="alt text" width="<?= $sizing_width ?>" height="<?= $sizing_height ?>" />
```

I would like to modify it so that I wouldn't have to do this for each image, but have one php command on a list of image. Is that possible?
After it's done, I plan to copy the output from the browser and then delete the command.

Comment: Yeah you could loop through the list and output each one

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PHP loop through folder and echo images in html error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21457874/php-loop-through-folder-and-echo-images-in-html-error)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```php
<?php
$paths = [
    $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] ."/path/file.jpg",
    ...
];
foreach ($paths as $path) {
    [$width, $height] = getimagesize($path);
?>
    <img src="<?= str_replace($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'], '', $path) ?>" alt="alt text" width="<?= $width ?>" height="<?= $height ?>" />
<?php
}
?>
```

Basically define all your image paths in a list and then loop over them printing out a new image with the sizes like you need.

Comment: This is a really good start. I almost got it to work. The only tweak I need is that $path will only work if in the "src" portion of the <img> tag if we could remove this: $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . and keep only "/path/file.jpg". The doc root still needs to be in $paths in order to obtain width and height.
But if it's too complicated, I can actually still work with this solution, because I can later do a find/replace in my editor. So for me, this is as good as done. Thanks

Comment: I've edit the answer to provide a fix for that. Basicall I just added a `str_replace` to remove `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` from the path, so you're left with just `/path/file.jpg`

Comment: Asis, that's brilliant! This works perfectly. Thank you